# C# Problem removing textbox from tableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, text, tablelayoutpanel

Hello I'm currently working on a windows from where I need to be able to add and remove a number of textboxes (and a lable) with a button click.
I have to have it set out within a tableLayoutPanel and Once "Add" is clicked a Label and 5 Text boxes must appear on the same row, and then when I click "Remove" they must dissapear, Hiding won't work as Data needs to be taken from them at a later stage but thats not an issue atm.

The problem is with the removal (I can add them fine as you'll see below) I know whats happening and can guess as to why but I need to find an alternate solution >.<

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
 {
    int Count = 1;
    int rowIndex = 2, colIndex = 1;
    Label Label;
    TextBox Value;
    TextBox Weight;
    TextBox Width;
    TextBox Height;
    TextBox Length;

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Count <= 9)
        {
            Count += 1;
            rowIndex += 1;
            tableLayoutPanel10.RowCount = +1;
            AddLot(Count);
            if (Count > 9)
                button1.Enabled = false;
        }

        button2.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Count == 2)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Label);
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Value);
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Weight);
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Width);
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Height);
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Length);
            Count -= 1;
            rowIndex -= 1;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Label);
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Value);
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Weight);
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Width);
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Height);
            tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Remove(Length);
            Count -= 1;
            rowIndex -= 1;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }


    }

    private void AddLot(int Count)
    {

        Label = new Label();
        Label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Label.Text = Count.ToString();
        Label.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;

        Value = new TextBox();
        Value.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        Weight = new TextBox();
        Weight.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        Width = new TextBox();
        Width.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        Height = new TextBox();
        Height.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        Length = new TextBox();
        Length.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Add(Label, colIndex - 1, rowIndex);
        tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Add(Value, colIndex, rowIndex);
        tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Add(Weight, colIndex + 1, rowIndex);
        tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Add(Width, colIndex + 2, rowIndex);
        tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Add(Height, colIndex + 3, rowIndex);
        tableLayoutPanel10.Controls.Add(Length, colIndex + 4, rowIndex);
    }


}
```

All That Happens when I try to remove is the Last added Row of label/textboxes is removed, and then only the rowindex/count decrease on any clocks afterwards.

Any Ideas how to get this to work, I'll accept having to change it almost completely but as I said It must be done in the TableLayoutPanel >.<

Cheers,
Jmaru7

Comment: ah, typo. but thats also remnant of something i'd tried before, changes nothing lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works 100% for me i spent an hour working on it :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 6;
            removeButton.Enabled = false;
        }

         private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1;
            Label label = new Label();
            TextBox Value = new TextBox();
            TextBox Weight = new TextBox();
            TextBox Width = new TextBox();
            TextBox Height = new TextBox();
            TextBox Length = new TextBox();

            label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            label.Text = (index + 1).ToString();
            label.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;

            Value.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            Weight.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            Width.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            Height.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            Length.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            int i = 0;
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label, i++, index);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Value, i++, index);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Weight, i++, index);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Width, i++, index);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Height, i++, index);
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Length, i++, index);

            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount += 1;

            if (tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount > 9)
            {
                addButton.Enabled = false;
            }

            if (tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount > 0)
            {
                removeButton.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount > 0)
            {
                int startIndex = ((tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1) * 6) - 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.RemoveAt(startIndex--);
                }

                tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount -= 1;

                if (tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount == 0)
                {
                    removeButton.Enabled = false;
                }

                if (tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount <= 9)
                {
                    addButton.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: even following this I seem to only get 1 row that moves down... don't know whats wrong now >.<

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping only last added set of controls, you should keep all of them. Now when you delete last added controls, next delete uses reference to already deleted so it wont have any effect.
Best would be to make some storage class for set of the controls and keep them in some kind of collection.